# Como exportar log das exceções do sqlite e python utilizando Import Error

Tags: python, exceção, sqlite3, log

Estou utilizando Python e dando import da biblioteca sqlite3 e do sqlite3 dando import no Error para tratamento de exceção!

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def errorlog(erro):
    errlog = open("err_log.txt", 'a')
    errlog.write(erro)
    errlog.close()


def conexaoBanco():
    con = None
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('banco.db')
    except Error as er:
        errorlog(er)
    return con
```

Porem a variavel er não contem uma string!
gerando este erro:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not OperationalError
```

Comment: É o que a mensagem de erro diz, o argumento da função deve ser `str` e não uma instancia de `OperationalError`. Teste `errlog.write(erro.message)`